# Screen rotation, getDuration(), illegalstateexception

Tags: android, rotation, android-mediaplayer, media

I'm having problems with resuming Media Player to it's previous state after rotating the screen. I've been trying to follow many example but neither of them is working for me.

For instance, I've been trying to:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt("position",mp.getCurrentPosition());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(savedInstanceState!= null){
            int position = savedInstanceState.getInt("position");
            mp.seekTo(position);
        }
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Yet, it completes successfully, then in the following part (`run()` method) that is fired right after `onRestoreInstanceState()`, I'm getting `IllegalStateException` while trying to ivoke the `getDuration()` method:

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
                long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(utilities.milisecondsToString(currentDuration));
                songTotalDurationLabel.setText(utilities.milisecondsToString(totalDuration));

                //ProgressBar
                songProgressBar.setProgress(utilities.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));

                //invoke that every 100ms
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };
```

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Your MediaPlayer instate might be killed when the screen rotate, so you need to prepare the MediaPlayer again before you can call the seekTo method.

Try to post your MediaPlayer preparation code for easier troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirements is to prevent your activity to be recreated during orientation change, you must tell your activity to handle orientation change by itself.

You can achieve this by adding `android:configChanges` attribute to your `<activity>` element.

```
<activity android:name=".MediaPlayerActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```